# NullReferenceExepction Error

Tags: unity

I'm getting error an error on this piece of code:

```
if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
     return;
```

The error:
`NullReferenceExpection: object reference not set to an instance of an object playercontroller.update() { at assets/script/palyer/playercontroller.cs:21)`

Any solution to this?

Comment: Maybe the `EventSystem` object was removed from the canvas.  Right click -> UI -> EventSystem to add it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is there to tell you what the problem is. A `NullReferenceException` means you tried to access a variable that is currently null:

```
Object a = null;
a.ToString();  <-- this line throws a NullReferenceException!
```

So in your case, assuming `EventSystem` is a class, `EventSystem.current` is null.

As this is Unity, the most likely issue is that you haven't added an EventSystem to your current scene, so there is no current EventSystem.